# What does the method clog() do?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am trying to learn url persistence, and a friend told me to study this block of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var objects = {};
var DEFAULT_LOCATION = "diameter";


$("#animateObjects").hide();


var urlDimension = location.hash.replace("#","");
if (urlDimension.length == 0) {
    // location.hash = "#" + DEFAULT_LOCATION;
    urlDimension = DEFAULT_LOCATION;
    $("#"+DEFAULT_LOCATION).addClass("active");
    clog("started with no dimension, defaulted to " + DEFAULT_LOCATION);
}
else {
    $("#"+urlDimension).toggleClass("active");
    clog("started with dimension: " + urlDimension);
}
```

What does the clog() method accomplish?

Full code is [here](https://github.com/VT-CHCI/scaling-dimensions/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/script.js.erb).

Comment: What else are you including?  It's not a standard function - I'd guess shorthand for `console.log`.  Try asking the friend who gave you the code.

Comment: What does the chat-gem in Diablo2 do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet its a wrapper around `console.log` to cater for IE not being able to handle it.

something like this:

```
function clog(message) {
    try {
        console.log('message');
    } 
    catch (ex) {}
}
```

Reference: http://benwong.me/javascript-console-log-and-internet-explorer/